# ElasticSearch: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, docker-compose

It seems like my SpringBoot application can't connect with ElasticSearch. I keep getting this error whenever i try to run my application:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticProductController' defined in URL [jar:file:/OnlineStore-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/kazantseva/project/OnlineStore/controller/rest/ElasticProductController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'elasticProductServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/OnlineStore-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/kazantseva/project/OnlineStore/service/impl/ElasticProductServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'elasticProductRepository' defined in kazantseva.project.OnlineStore.repository.elasticSearch.ElasticProductRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on OnlineStoreApplication: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception

 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticProductServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/OnlineStore-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/kazantseva/project/OnlineStore/service/impl/ElasticProductServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'elasticProductRepository' defined in kazantseva.project.OnlineStore.repository.elasticSearch.ElasticProductRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on OnlineStoreApplication: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception

 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticProductRepository' defined in kazantseva.project.OnlineStore.repository.elasticSearch.ElasticProductRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on OnlineStoreApplication: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception

 | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

My ElasticProductRepository.java file :

```
public interface ElasticProductRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ElasticProduct, String> {
}
```

My ElasticProductServiceImpl.java file :

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ElasticProductServiceImpl implements ElasticProductService {

    private ElasticProductRepository elasticProductRepository;

    @Override
    public List<ElasticProduct> getAllProducts() {
        return (List<ElasticProduct>) elasticProductRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public ElasticProduct insertProduct(ElasticProduct product) {
        return elasticProductRepository.save(product);
    }
}
```

My ElasticSearchConfig.java file :

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
public class ElasticSearchConfig extends ElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    public @NotNull ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
        return ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                .build();
    }
}
```

My pom.xml :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

My application.properties :

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
spring.elasticsearch.uris=https://localhost:9200
```

My docker-compose.yml :

```
 version: '3.7'
services:
  elastic-service:
    image: elasticsearch:8.8.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - "my-net"


  mysql-service:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql-db
    env_file:
      - api.env
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - "my-net"


  mongo-service:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo-db
    env_file:
      - api.env
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - "my-net"
  
  onlinestore:
    image: online-store
    container_name: online-store-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/www/images/customers:/tmp/images/customers
      - /var/www/images/products:/tmp/images/products
    depends_on:
      - mysql-service
      - mongo-service
      - elastic-service
    env_file:
      - api.env
      - prod.env
    user: "1000:1000"
    networks:
      - "my-net"

networks:
  my-net:
    driver: bridge
```

I use Spring Boot 3.0.6 and ElasticSearch 8.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running container with security enabled by default, so it will require **HTTPS** connection and will have some generated password **credentials**.

---

To start it on a http and without creds - use **xpack.security.enabled=false** flag

```
version: "3"
services:
  es:
    image: elasticsearch:8.8.1
    container_name: elastic
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-cluster
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.security.enrollment.enabled=false
      - cluster.name="docker-cluster"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./es/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw
      - ./es/logs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs:rw
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - es-network
networks:
  es-network:
    driver: bridge
```

---

P.S

You don't need
public class **ElasticSearchConfig**
because your application.properties already has everything you need.

Comment: I removed ElasticSearchConfig class and added disable security to docker-compose but nothing changed and I still get these errors at startup.

Comment: @Sonnka fixed docker compose and tested it - at my computer its a fully functional single node elastic

Comment: try new docker-compose file)

Comment: Thanks, yes, elasticsearch is working, but when I run just it and my web app. But I also have mysql and mongo in docker compose and when I run everything together via docker compose I get these errors. And what is interesting, after less than 1 minute http://localhost:9200 starts working, but I still keep getting these errors. Btw, I updated docker compose in post.

Comment: I found mistake. In application.properties must be elastic-service:9200 instead of localhost:9200.